# Top X users for piechart, remaining after X grouped into other

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am looking to modify a query I have used at fetching the top 5 users for piechart data by adding another section called "other" which the remaining users are grouped into.

For example, I have 10 users, and I want to grab the top 5 commentors, and the remaining 5 are under a single totaled result called "other" or something similar.

Example code:

```
SELECT user_id, count(user_id) as cnt
from users
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY cnt desc 
LIMIT 5
```

Would grab the top 5, I dont know what to add to total the remaining users into a 6th result which is the sum of all of their posts. (Ie if the last 5 users post 15 articles, the cnt for the 6th row would be 15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the grouping like you already did first, then add a row counter in an outer query, but let the rowcounter always have the same value when it's above a certain level (in your case 5). Then in the outermost query you group by this rowcounter.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(cnt) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT cnt, @rowcnt := @rowcnt + 1,
    IF(@rowcnt <= 5, user_id, 'other') AS user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, count(user_id) as cnt
        from users
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) sq
    , (SELECT @rowcnt := 0) var_init_subquery_alias
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
) ssq
LEFT JOIN comments c ON ssq.user_id = c.user_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, since there won't be comments for user_id "other".

Comment: Woah thats way more than I expected. I assumed I might be able to use a limit of 5 on the first one then do something like a union to a second query to do the exact same but grab all but the first 5 and then total that entire result set. I am worried about all the subqueries as I have over 20 million rows and It may affect performance. Is there anything more direct like 2 unions?

Comment: If we were to use a union, on the second query could I simply use a "AND NOT IN" and give it the results of the first query?

Comment: You're doing a full table scan with your query anyway. You're doing two queries with `union`. I am doing one query. Have a try with `union` and my approach and compare the execution times. :)

Comment: Ah I see. Question, is "@rowcnt" a predefined variable? And how is ":=" different from just "="?

Comment: @rowcnt is initialized in the subquery I cross-joined in the subquery. `:=` is the assignment operator, `=` tests for equality.

Comment: In the `SET` statement it's okay to use it this way. Don't worry.

Comment: If the comments are in a table called "comments" where would the join go? In the inner inner select, the inner select or in the outer one?

Comment: If it's joined to the user_id, join in the outer most query. Edited my answer.

Comment: I noticed a bug with this. Its including 1 for every user even if they dont have a corresponding comment (I assume because since the user exists, its a count and then each join ups the count). But if no one has comments I still get a list of 5 users with a cnt of 1 and the "other" is just the sum of all the users.

Comment: Also, I have a point system that assigns X by users in a points table (points.comments_id, points.amount). I cant for the life of me figure out how to get a sum of all the points for each user organized in the same way. Think of it like money being added to a comment and an admin can add money more than once to a comment with each add as a separare row. So i need to see who collected the most money top 5 down with the 6th as other.

Sorry for being such a noob but Im really struggling with this type of sub set of queries.

Comment: If its not against the rules maybe you could help me 1on1 and then I could pay you something we decide on via paypal? I really need this working and I just kind of was given this project with very little notice :(

Comment: A left join gives you every entry from the left table, regardless of if there's an entry on the joined table. If you want just users who have a comment, change it to an inner join. That being said, your problem is quite unclear to me, but it sounds much like it's a whole different question. So treat it like that. Create a new question here on SO, post the link here and I'll have a look at it (when I have the time).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(counter) FROM 
(SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 
CASE WHEN @rownum <= 5 THEN user_id ELSE 'Other' END AS user_id,
count(user_id) as counter
FROM users, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r GROUP BY user_id) hellTemp
GROUP BY user_id
```

***[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bd99/8)***

Comment: Thanks This seems a little more direct/easier to understand. Is there a recommendation to use this one or the one provided by fancypants?

Comment: Well, this solution is wrong. Though it's a bit nicer with the CASE WHEN, wanted to implement this in my solution, too.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. See this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b99/3/0 Result should be 1, 2, not 1, 4